Froala class names for select item in custom popup
I've created a custom popup for froala but can't seem to find the relevant class names for my select elements:

For the first two fields no problem I have .fr-input-line and .fr-link-attr.fr-not-empty but in the docs and css I can't find anything like .fr-select-line.
IS there anywhere I can see a list of elements and their class names?
